# Powerform Docusign connect envelope signed notification

Tags: docusignapi, powerform

We have embedded docusign using powerform by using demo account within iframe. I am working on how to configure docusign connect.

Which URL I need to mention for publishing in demo account and how docusign is connected with powerform. Do we get any data or event notifications of every signers in docusign connect?

Answer (score 0):

Powerform is a UI flow provided by DocuSign to capture the signer details like Name/Email and then trigger the signing ceremony, so once all the signer details are captures and Powerform is triggered then an envelope is also created. So DocuSign then maintains the workflow of that Powerform. Now to capture the DS Connect events, you need to develop a listener which can accept an XML message, once listener is developed by you, then you need to configure same listener in your DocuSign account, [DS Connect Configuration](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-custom-connect-configuration-htm) will help you in configuring the listener. There are many types of trigger events, both at envelope and recipient level, so based on your usecase, you can subscribed to these events and DocuSign will push XML messages to you as soon as subscribed events get triggered in the envelope workflow.

Comment: Thank you Amit..But I am using demo account for listener which URL i need to publish

Comment: I am working on docusign using powerform within iframe. I added java script to my HTML on the return url page as a result all the parameters(envelope,pf and r ID) are displaying. If second user signs the document return page should be displayed with unique parameters I mean dynamically but its displaying the same parameters. Please do assist regarding this issue.

Comment: Can you try opening powerform URL directly in browser, instead of your IFrame and see if this issue exists.